# Obtain angles of rotation from singular vectors U and V from SVD

Tags: matrix, rotation, geometric-transform

My question is a continuation to a [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259059/solving-a-system-of-coupled-trigonometric-equations-to-find-angles) question. I have a matrix M which is a function of theta1, theta2, phi1 and phi2. Now, I want to get back these angles using the singular vectors (U and V) of an SVD ($U.W.V^{T}$).
I want to start by taking a random matrix M and try to extract these angles by manipulating matrices U and V.
I however took it a bit different way. I tried to come up with a combination of rotations T1 and T2 that gives a similar matrix as U and V but not exactly the same. So, I cannot equate them as I had initially thought.
Here's my code:

```
M={{161.294, 11.3761, 60.498}, {-10.7667, -7.11777, 30.0436}, {-64.1061,
   29.8182, -15.9093}};

{U, W, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[M];
U
V

Uy[theta] = {{Cos[theta]],0,Sin[theta]},{0,1,0},{-Sin[theta],0,Cos[theta]}};
Uz[phi] = {{Cos[phi],-Sin[phi],0},{Sin[phi],Cos[phi],0},{0,0,1}};
T1 = Uy[theta1]
T2 = Uy[theta2].Uz[phi1].Uz[phi2]
```

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Avoid using MatrixForm (which is really just for pretty printing matrices) when you set variables like T1,T2,  as this wraps a MatrixForm head around the expression and it won't work as expected in any future computations you do with these variables.